# C++/CLI function call missing argument list; use to create a pointer to member

Tags: .net, visual-studio, delegates, c++-cli

I'm using C++/CLI.
I need to pass void as a function argument. Functions argument is a delegate void

I get the following error 
error C3867: 'ChartTestApplication::UIMain::ChartCursorSelected': function call missing argument list; use '&ChartTestApplication::UIMain::ChartCursorSelected' to create a pointer to member

Here is the class where I define the function

```
namespace charting 
{

public delegate void CursorPositionChanged(double x, double y);

public ref class ChartTest sealed abstract
{
static void MyFunc(Chart ^sender, CursorPositionChanged ^selectionChanged, CursorPositionChanged ^cursorMoved)
{
   // Some code here
}

}

}
```

And here is the other class where I want to call MyFunc function

```
void UIMain::ChartCursorSelected(double x, double y)
    {
        txtChartSelect->Text = x.ToString("F4") + ", " + y.ToString("F4");
    }

    void UIMain::ChartCursorMoved(double x, double y)
    {
        txtChartValue->Text = x.ToString("F4") + ", " + y.ToString("F4");
    }

    System::Void UIMain::UIMain_Shown(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        ChartTest ::MyFunc(this->mainChart, this->ChartCursorSelected, this->ChartCursorMoved);
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: The error message tells you what code you need to write, hard to see why you didn't try it.  The [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx) has explicit examples.

Comment: I know about it. Mine is different situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code sample. As Hans Passant suggested, you might want to read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx) about delegates in C++/CLI.

```
namespace charting 
{
    public delegate void CursorPositionChanged(double x, double y);

    public ref class ChartTest sealed abstract
    {
    public:
        static void MyFunc(ref class Chart ^sender, CursorPositionChanged^, CursorPositionChanged^) { }
    };

    public ref class Chart { };

    public ref class UIMain
    {
    public:
        UIMain()
            : mainChart(gcnew Chart) { }

        void ChartCursorSelected(double x, double y) { }

        void ChartCursorMoved(double x, double y) { }

        System::Void UIMain_Shown(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
        {
            ChartTest::MyFunc(
                this->mainChart,
                gcnew CursorPositionChanged(this, &UIMain::ChartCursorSelected),
                gcnew CursorPositionChanged(this, &UIMain::ChartCursorMoved)
                );
        }

        Chart^ mainChart;
    };
}
```